# How to set caption skip for longtable

Tags: captions, longtable, vskip

I tried `\belowcaptionskip` and `\abovecaptionskip`. No effects.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs}
\setlength\abovecaptionskip{10pt}
\setlength\belowcaptionskip{30pt}

\title{test}
\begin{document}
This is a test table.

\begin{longtable}[]{@{}cl@{}}
\caption{test table}\tabularnewline
\toprule
col1 & col2\tabularnewline
\midrule
\endhead
1 & 2\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

End of the document.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Add `\usepackage{caption}` to your preamble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `caption`package, this works:

```
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[longtable]{skip=30pt}
```